# Function always missing 1 required positional argument when stored in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to store functions in a list and then later in a program call those functions from that list with values also stored on that list.

Example:

```
import random
import time

ranges = 23,24
my_functions_and_values = [[random.randint, ranges], [time.sleep, 2]]

for i in my_functions_and_values:
    i[0](i[1])
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the parameters to functions as tuples (so `2` will become `(2, )`). Then when you call the function do parameter unpacking with `*`:

```
import random
import time

ranges = 23,24
my_functions_and_values = [[random.randint, ranges], [time.sleep, (2, )]]

for i in my_functions_and_values:
    i[0](*i[1])
```